# How to set this CSS arrow transparent?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get this result :

[image]

And here is what I have for now (I'm only trying to get the result on the left element for the moment) :

[image]

I am trying to have this left arrow transparent but I can't find how to do that.

CSS Code :

```
.main_container .photo_container .mask a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 25px;
    position: relative;
}

.main_container .photo_container .mask a:first-child {
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    padding: 5px 11px 7px;
}

.main_container .photo_container .mask a:first-child::before {
    border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
    border-right: 7px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-top: 7px solid transparent;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    left: -8px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
}
.main_container .photo_container .mask a:first-child::after {
    border-bottom: 24px solid transparent;
    border-right: 25px solid #eee;
    border-top: 24px solid transparent;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    left: -26px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
}
```

HTML Code :

```
<div class="photo_container">
    <img src="images/placeholder/car1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
    <div class="mask">
        <a href=""><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
        <a href=""><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can you help me?

Comment: what about using [clip-path](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind using [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) this is pretty simple:

Making a pseudo element after the existing one, centering it on the correct side, and rotating it by 45 degrees.

The 70.71% figure is gotten using [`s = q / sqrt(2)`](http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/geometry-plane/squares.php) where `s` is the side of a square, and `q` is the diagonal.

```
.arrow
{
    border:             1px white;
    border-style:       solid solid solid none;
    position:           relative;
    width:              50px;
    height:             50px;
}

.arrow::after
{
    content:            "";
    display:            block;
    top:                50%;
    left:               0;
    position:           absolute;
    border:             1px white;
    border-style:       none none solid solid;
    width:              70.71%; /* the side of a square is 70.71% the length of it's diagonal */
    height:             70.71%;
    transform:          translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
}
```

Finally, we can change what borders are shown, and the absolute positioning to make the arrow appear on the desired side:

```css
body
{
 background-color:     black;
 padding:              50px;
}

.arrow_left,
.arrow_right
{
 display:            inline-block; /* just to get them next to eachother */
 border:             1px white;
 position:           relative;
 width:              50px;
 height:             50px;
}

.arrow_left  { border-style: solid solid solid none; }
.arrow_right { border-style: solid none solid solid; }

.arrow_left::after,
.arrow_right::after
{
 content:            "";
 display:            block;
 top:                50%;
 position:           absolute;
 border:             1px white;
 width:              70.71%; /* the side of a square is 70.71% the length of it's diagonal */
 height:             70.71%;
 transform:          translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
}

.arrow_left::after
{
 left:               0;
 border-style:       none none solid solid;
}

.arrow_right::after
{
 left:               100%;
 border-style:       solid solid none none;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow_left"></div>
<div class="arrow_right"></div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a working demo? The OP doesn't have any classes called `arrow` so it's hard to know where you intend this to be applied

Comment: @musefan unfortunately no - CSS Desk, JSFiddle and everything else like it are blocked at my office.  I can add that when I get home, but really, the CSS is there, it can be plugged directly into a browser with any `DIV.arrow`, and askers are expected to do some of their own work.

Comment: [does seem to work](http://jsfiddle.net/wc4p7w8s/), though it looks like it can easily break if not careful

Comment: @musefan thank you - I've added a link to the Fiddle.  What about it seems like it could break?  It does not support non-square DIVs, but that's about it.

Comment: Ha, good question. I don't know. I tried to add the font awesome icons in (as per question) but it went wrong and the triangle vanished, I might have more of a play, and will update the link if I get it working with the icons

Comment: @musefan that's an excellent point.  FontAwesome uses `::before` to place its icons - you may be able to avoid it using `::after` instead

Comment: @musefan Checked, `::after` fixes the issue.  Updating answer.  Good catch, you should probably update the fiddle, too!

Comment: Provided updated link. I have included both left and right arrows, and it includes font-awesome too. I haven't make it look great though. Icons and arrows need to be fiddled with to align, but it certainly proves the concept works! Anyway... good answer!

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith: Nope, can't help you with that one

Comment: Trolling? Are the goats after the good grass again? ...little buggers

Answer (score 0):

The left 'arrow' cannot be transparent, because in reality it is just a solid border applied to 1/4 of a box.

(See this [article](http://appendto.com/2013/03/pure-css-triangles-explained/) explaining how the css triangle effect is achieved.)

You will either need to use images, or tweak the graphic design.

Answer (score 0):

You tried use border to achieve transparent triangle. It doesn't work. So let's think about other way to implement what we want. 
I created simple demo - any triangle is made by 2 lines (simple trigonometry knowledge needed.) 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPbxEQ - i used some variables in css, so in that case i used stylus - more prefer read the source code, not just compiled result. 
We create a pseudo element for first icon. Rotate it and evaluate new height. Than change transform-origin. Easy.

We change the angle - and recalculate the cos(angle);

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url("http://7-themes.com/data_images/out/2/6775415-beautiful-images.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.Icons {
  width: 50vmin;
  height: 25vmin;
  display: flex;
}
.Icon {
  flex: 1;
  border-color: currentColor;
  border-style: solid;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(2vw + 2vh + 4vmin);
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}
.Icon + .Icon {
  margin-left: -1px;
}
.Icon:first-of-type {
  border-width: 1px 1px 1px 0;
}
.Icon:last-of-type {
  border-width: 1px 0 1px 1px;
}
.Icon:first-of-type:before,
.Icon:first-of-type:after,
.Icon:last-of-type:before,
.Icon:last-of-type:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: currentColor;
  width: 1px;
  height: calc(50% / 0.866025404); /* Our angle is 30deg, so formula is calc(50% / cos(angle)) */
}
.Icon:first-of-type:before,
.Icon:first-of-type:after {
  left: 0;
}
.Icon:first-of-type:before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotateZ(30deg);
  transform-origin: top;
}
.Icon:first-of-type:after {
  bottom: 0;
  transform: rotateZ(-30deg);
  transform-origin: bottom;
}
.Icon:last-of-type:before,
.Icon:last-of-type:after {
  right: 0;
}
.Icon:last-of-type:before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotateZ(-30deg);
  transform-origin: top;
}
.Icon:last-of-type:after {
  bottom: 0;
  transform: rotateZ(30deg);
  transform-origin: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="Icons">
  <div class="Icon">I</div>
  <div class="Icon">O</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also you could probably use SVG.

Comment: Looks really good, thank you very much for your work and efforts! I ended up using the PSD image finally. Wanted a CSS version to manage "hovers" easily, but my client doesn't need this finally. But I keep your version too because it learnt me a lot! Thanks!